# Is there anyway to spread the return of a function call into props in jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx, spread-syntax

I can't come up with a way to do it, but what I want is:

```
<ColumnDef key="label" ...createCommonColumnProps.call(this, {somestuff}) />
<ColumnDef key="count" ...createCommonColumnProps.call(this, {someOtherStuff}) />
<ColumnDef key="value" ...createCommonColumnProps.call(this, {yetOtherstuff}) />
```

I'm hoping it stupidly simple and I'm just being an idiot, but I can't find a way to do it without creating variables like

```
<ColumnDef key="label" {...column1} />
<ColumnDef key="count" {...column2} />
<ColumnDef key="value" {...column3} />
```

There are about 5 props, some of which are affected by the object passed to the function.

When I'm trying this in the chrome devtools console (just the js part, not the jsx part), I'm seeing things like this:

```
> function a() {
   return {a:1, b:2}
 }
undefined
> y = {... a()}
VM341:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
> x = ... a()
VM368:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
> x = {a:1,b:2}
Object {a: 1, b: 2}
> y = {...x}
VM888:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
```

Comment: `{...createCommonColumnProps.call(this, {somestuff})}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSX object expansion syntax looks like:

```
{...<expression>}
```

Where `expression` returns a reference to an object.

So in your case it would be

```
<ColumnDef key="label" {... createCommonColumnProps.call(this, {somestuff})} />
```

**UPD** to reflect your question update:

> When I'm trying this in the chrome devtools console (just the js part, not the jsx part), I'm seeing things like this:

That's happening because even though JSX object spread syntax is looking similar to the non standardised yet ES object spread syntax - they are not interchangeable (and the chrome does not support the latter yet).

So, just use it exactly as I demonstrated in the example above.

Comment: Maybe it's just the chrome console, but I'm running into this:

    ```x = ... a();
    VM368:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...```

Comment: @boatcoder what exactly do you run? Google chrome does not support JSX.

Comment: But it does support most of ES6

Comment: It does. JSX is an independent standard though. What exactly do you run in console and what is the problem now?

Comment: Updated the question, beginning to think this is a chrome console limitation, going to have to try it with babel now.

Comment: @boatcoder you are confusing the ES6 object spread syntax (which actually is not standardised yet) and JSX object spread syntax. They look similar but totally independent things. Don't treat them interchangeable. Your initial question is about JSX object spread - so use it in JSX as I shown in the example.

Comment: I was indeed confusing them and was not aware the they were different.  I also thought there was more es6 in chrome than there actually was.

Comment: @boatcoder well, chrome supports the ES2015 entirely (but modules), ES2016 entirely, and ES2017 partially. The object spread is simply not a real standard yet https://github.com/tc39/proposals Additionally see http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: @boatcoder: `x = ... a();` is not valid ES6 and wouldn't be allowed in any proposal either. **`...` [is not an operator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37151966/218196)!** It's part of specific syntax constructs such as array literals, array destructuring, function calls, function definitions (all ES6), object literals, object destructuring (proposal) and JSX elements (non-standard).